# Retrieving code for Spore from 2010

Tags: spore

So I bought Spore several years ago, apparently in 2010, and haven't played it in a while. I decided today I wanted to play it again, and it asked me for a registration code. I searched my email and found a spore related email from 2010. The email says it is confirmation of my registration, but there is no registration code in it.

Here is a picture of the email:

[image: Spore Email]

It says if the email is blocked, click here, but that takes me to an empty page. I"m not sure if this is the right forum for this, but it seems like a good start. If anyone has any ideas, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Info below is from the spore forums : http://forum.spore.com/jforum/posts/list/14359.page#206299

> If your game was registered you can go to http://support.ea.com, click My Account, then My Games. After you have logged in, you can go to the My Games tab and it should have your key there.

If it was not registered, you will need to obtain a new code

> If you meet one of the following criteria, you can send a request along with a nominal fee to Electronic Arts for a replacement serial number.
>
> - The product is 90 days past the purchase date
> - The original serial number has been discarded or lost
>
> When sending a request for a replacement serial number, please include the following:
>
> - A money order for $10.00 USD (per serial number requested) made payable to Electronic Arts.
>     o Note: If you are requesting serial numbers for a collection pack, the $10.00 USD fee will cover numbers for all of the games included in the package.
> - The proof of purchase page from your manual (If you no longer have the manual, include one of the game disks as verification of ownership.
>     o Note: If sending a disk as verification, please send it using a traceable method as Electronic Arts is not responsible for products not in its possession.
>     Explanation of the situation
> - First and Last Name
> - Return Address
> - E-mail Address
> - Phone Number

(New to the site, if this answer is wrong feel free to downvote to hell or even delete the answer :P)

Comment: Please summarize the information in the link.  That way, if ever the page goes down, your answer is still valid.

Comment: @Frank although the forum has been up for 8 years, I guess that is a possibility, I'll work on that right now..